# Model.addAttribute from several tables

Tags: hibernate, jsp

I have entity Card_Balance. When i want display it on JSP I write method

```
Card_Balance find_by_id{
 String que = "SELECT * FROM Card_Balance  WHERE Card_Balance.CARD_ID="+id;
 SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(que).addEntity(Card_Balance.class);
 ...
}
```

And use it in controller. Now i want display JSP table use two entity.
I write sql

```
SELECT  FROM  BALANCE_HIST BH 
INNER JOIN EVENTS EV ON       
BH.DATE_EVENT=EV.PAYMENT_TIME 
WHERE BH.CARD_ID ="+id;
```

And I do not know what to do next. What should the method return? How to use it in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen an incorrect way.

```
CardBalance findById(Long id) {
  return (CardBalance)session.get(CardBalance.class, id);
}

List<BalanceHistory> getHistoryByCardId(Long cardId) {
  String hql = "from BalanceHistory history where history.card.id = :cardId";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("cardId", cardId);
  return (List<BalanceHistory>)query.list();
}
```

This is just an example. Method `getByCardId()` returns a list of `BalanceHistory` for a card with `cardId`.

I make an assumption for `BalanceHistory`

```
@Entity
class BalanceHistory {

  @ManyToOne
  private CardBalance card;

}
```

Comment: Finally we used DTO pattern